# How to build a TM state diagram for a given language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I came across following TM state diagram accepting language $\{a^nb^nc^n | n\geq 0\}$
[image]

After trying out some valid and invalid strings of various lengths, I was surprised how it is designed to accept language exactly as specified.

Now I have started wondering how I can come up with such TM design given any language specification. When I learned FAs and NFAs, I came across some minimal regexes ($\epsilon$, a, a+b, a*, ab) whose FAs are well known. Then we can combine these FAs to come up with more FAs/NFAs for more complex regexes / languages. Is there any such standard way / approach to come up with TM design for given language? Or is it pure creativity/intuition to design approach.

Comment: I would be surprised if there where a large enough body of examples for coming up with TMs that such design patterns could emerge. Unlike DFAs having concrete TMs for given problems doesn't seem very useful in practice.

Comment: As far as coming up with a TM is the same as programming on a computer, do you think there is a standard approach for all problems? Why then we need programmers at all? For easy languages there are easy TMs which are considered classical, but you can easily define sophisticated languages.

Comment: Moreover, answering the question about TM which solves SAT (determ. of course) would answer the question P=NP, and if there were a standardized way to do this, we wouldn't be struggling for so long.

Comment: Arghhh...right then, its a skill, programming is the skill...I was unnecessarily generalizing what was possible for FAs/NFAs should also be possible for TMs. May be sudden concentrated overdose of the subject made me forget this obvious fact.